# After exporting to Unity, character animations stuck in T pose

Tags: animation, rigging, export, unity

When exporting Model, Rig and Animation to Unity, the animations seem to not carry over.
On my animation preview screen the character is permanently stuck in T pose!

I have tried generic and humanoid rig in Unity both to no result so I am assuming there must be a trick that I am missing when it comes to animations/models in blender, so i recorded myself exporting.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DT_b6k4YBys

[image: Export Settings]

I read on another post that Unity doesn't support Blender Envelope weighing, only vertex weighing, does this mean i cant use "parent with automatic weights", or is it referring to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, in blender if you have your model in "Rest Position" instead of "Pose Position" while exporting then the model will be locked into rest position even in Unity, even in animations
[image]